# Use for loop print string in multi-line

Tags: python, string, for-loop

I have a string: `qwerasdfzxcv`

I want to print:

```
qwer
asdf
zxcv
```

I want to know how to print in the above mentioned format.

Comment: four element in each token?

Comment: Which language. How do you determine the 'split' point (Every 4 chars? / Split the string into 3 equal parts?).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe an easier-to-read approach, using a for loop:

```
word = 'qwerasdfzxcv'
chunk_size = 4
for index in range(0,len(word),chunk_size):
    print( word[index:index+chunk_size] )
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to achieve the output that you mentioned.

```
var = 'qwerasdfzxcv'
idx = 0
while idx < len(var):
  print(var[idx:idx+4])
  idx += 4
```

**Output**

```
qwer 
asdf 
zxcv
```